# Moving Object A to random position of other X objects

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, button

Here is what i want to do, this is supposed to work something like a hint button. When clicked on Object A, which is a loupe, it is supposed to move to random position of one of X hidden objects and then return after like 3 seconds. Here is what i tried:

```
public class Lupica1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //List of positions
    public Transform[] positions;
    //Just holds the index of picked random position
    private int br;
    private Transform target;
    private float speed = 1f;
    private Vector3 OrgPos;
    private float timer = 3f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Stores the original of position of ObjectA(loupe)
        OrgPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        //Index of random position is picked here
        br = Random.Range(0, positions.Length);
        //And stored into target
        target = positions[br];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Timer 
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    //This is the method to assign to onClick function in Inspector 
    public void Lupica()
    {   
        
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(gameObject.transform.position, target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //When timer reaches 0, return object A(loupe) to original position
        if (timer < 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = OrgPos;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start a coroutine in `Lupica` and handle all of the movement and timer logic in there:

```
//List of positions
public Transform[] positions;
//Just holds the index of picked random position
private int br;
private Transform target;
private float speed = 1f;
private Vector3 OrgPos;
private float timer = 3f;
private Coroutine lupicaCoroutine = null;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Stores the original of position of ObjectA(loupe)
    OrgPos = transform.position;
    //Index of random position is picked here
    br = Random.Range(0, positions.Length);
    //And stored into target
    target = positions[br];
}

public void Lupica()
{   
    if (lupicaCoroutine != null) return;

    lupicaCoroutine = StartCoroutine(HandleLoupe());
}

private IEnumerator HandleLoupe()
{
    while (transform.position != target.position)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
                target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);

    transform.position = OrgPos;
    lupicaCoroutine = null;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, i mean nothing happens, when i click on it, it doesn't move

Comment: Did you drag into the button the `Lupica1` that you defined `positions` for? if you drag from assets that's not the same as the one in the scene. Include `Debug.Log($"{GetInstanceID()}");` in `Start` and `Lupica` and if they print different, then they are different instances and you need to make the button knows about the one that runs with `Start`.

Comment: Yes i know, i dragged 4 elements from the scene to the inspector

Comment: Can i put it to be GameObject with collider, and then to if raycast hits it, then start coroutine and move to random positioN?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in `Lupica` and click it, what does your debugger say you have for `target.position`? What about `transform.position`?

Comment: Anything could run `Lupica` and it should work as long as it occurs after `Start` runs, and it has at least one element in `positions`

Comment: In 3 tries for target.position it picks the same position and there is nothing for transform.position

Comment: Nothing for `transform.position`? That's pretty weird. I'm not altogether convinced this instance actually exists in the scene.... What gets printed if you include `Debug.Log($"{gameObject.scene.name!=null}");` at the start of `Lupica`? Also, I am still curious if `Debug.Log($"{GetInstanceID()}");` prints different things in `Start` vs `Lupica`.

Comment: Debug.Log($"{GetInstanceID()}"); This one prints out the same message: 35588
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object), and the other one prints out True